# extract high res images with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract all high res images links using this regex.

```
(?<=hiRes":").*(?=")
```

but my result is messedup

how can do it better?

the html is this

```
'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81Xd1Dl5eQL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51ClqURqRbL._SS40_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51ClqURqRbL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81Xd1Dl5eQL._SY355_.jpg":[237,355],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81Xd1Dl5eQL._SY450_.jpg":[300,450],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81Xd1Dl5eQL._SY550_.jpg":[367,550],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81Xd1Dl5eQL._SY606_.jpg":[404,606],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81Xd1Dl5eQL._SY679_.jpg":[453,679]},"variant":"MAIN"},{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91EYqpvWBHL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51pXpQ8N0AL._SS40_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51pXpQ8N0AL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91EYqpvWBHL._SY355_.jpg":[237,355],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91EYqpvWBHL._SY450_.jpg":[300,450],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91EYqpvWBHL._SY550_.jpg":[367,550],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91EYqpvWBHL._SY606_.jpg":[404,606],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91EYqpvWBHL._SY679_.jpg":[453,679]},"variant":"PT01"},{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OXAHjs6TL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41O2XWvKUtL._SS40_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41O2XWvKUtL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OXAHjs6TL._SY355_.jpg":[237,355],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OXAHjs6TL._SY450_.jpg":[300,450],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OXAHjs6TL._SY550_.jpg":[367,550],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OXAHjs6TL._SY606_.jpg":[404,606],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81OXAHjs6TL._SY679_.jpg":[453,679]},"variant":"PT02"},{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91WRJ5PGuaL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51RoDsuFLBL._SS40_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51RoDsuFLBL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91WRJ5PGuaL._SY355_.jpg":[237,355],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91WRJ5PGuaL._SY450_.jpg":[300,450],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91WRJ5PGuaL._SY550_.jpg":[367,550],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91WRJ5PGuaL._SY606_.jpg":[404,606],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91WRJ5PGuaL._SY679_.jpg":[453,679]},"variant":"PT03"},{"hiRes":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81sbWvBpihL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51hsnHI%2BaXL._SS40_.jpg","large":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51hsnHI%2BaXL.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81sbWvBpihL._SY355_.jpg":[285,355],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81sbWvBpihL._SY450_.jpg":[362,450],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81sbWvBpihL._SX425_.jpg":[425,529],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81sbWvBpihL._SX466_.jpg":
```

Comment: `(?<=hiRes":")([^"]*)(?=")`

Comment: A different way: try to extract the JSON from HTML, use a lib or a tool like *jq* to extract all hiRes URLs.

Comment: Is this actually legal to do? Is Amazon okay with people obtaining this image in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<="hiRes":")(.*?)(?=")
```

[regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/qO1oX7/1)

Comment: exactly what i need, thaks Sergey!